# Google Maps Api call from server

Tags: java, android, google-maps, server

Is there any way that I can call Google Maps Web APIs from my application server i.e. I mean to say from the Java code or from any server side code without having any JavaScript involved?

As we can call these map api from our android application provided our manifest file contains API KEY. But how to achieve that on my application server which will control that android application.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.[Google maps web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/) contains many service.Which service are you talking about ?

Comment: I am talking about if I can call these web services from my application server? consider it as place api

Answer (score 4):

Since i have recently worked with distance matrix API that's why i am referring that example. For google API call from your application server first you need to add the library to your project via Maven.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also add gradle dependencies.Then follow this below example

```
LatLng origin, LatLng destination
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
    .apiKey(your_google_api_key)
    .build(); 

//This one is for asynchronous calling style
DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context).origins(origin).destinations(destination)
              .setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DistanceMatrix>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DistanceMatrix result) { 

                 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                 System.out.println(gson.toJson(result.rows[0].elements[0].duration));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                // Handle error.
                }
    });
```

Requests support synchronous calling style too. Automatic retry when intermittent failures occur is also provided. For more in-depth knowledge and features please look at this official [documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)